# Updating an attribute in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-update

I am trying to update an attribute of a field.

For example, updating the name "Orchid garden" to a new name, let's say, "The Beautiful Garden"...

I am following the syntax given in the MongoDB Documentation but it seems that I am missing something.

(The database is called plants.)

[The field information is written in JSON, click here to preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF4Jh.png)

Here is what I was trying:

```
db.gardens.update( {name: "Orchid Garden"}, {$set: {name : "Gothenburg Orchid Garden"}}  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested `garden` object so you have to use the dot notation

```
db.gardens.update( {"garden.name": "Orchid Garden"}, {$set: {"garden.name" : "Gothenburg Orchid Garden"}} )
```